# the command "netstat -p" doesn't display the pid

Tags: shell, netstat

the shell command netstat -p , doesn't display the pid.
It displays "-" like this:

```
tcp        0      0 *:2181 *:53837 ESTABLISHED -
```

why?

It still display "-" although I use root to login.

Comment: Giving out OS name, distribution, source of your netstat program, etc, would be really helpful.

Comment: did u find the answer?

Answer (score 6):

Use `sudo` to see all fields.

```
$ sudo netstat -p
```

Also, I like to use `sudo netstat -pant` because it is easy to remember, and I'm almost always only interested in seeing the TCP info.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a permissions problem, you can try sudo ?

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the following documentation regarding netstat command:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/modules/ps2643/products_tech_note09186a00800fad79.shtml

try the command with sudo and see

---

### sudo netstat -p

Comment: It still display "-" although I use root to login.